# How to apply Css/JQuery files to an external page inside Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

Not sure if what I had in mind is possible or not, but why now.

I have a MVC4 Master page as follows

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>RYTE HCMS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="<%: Url.Content("~/favicon.ico") %>" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrap {
            white-space: normal !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-url="master-page" id="master-page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Header" runat="server">
                <a href="#leftpanel" data-panelid="leftpanel" data-icon="bars" data-role="link" style="height: 17px"></a>
                <h1>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
                </h1>
                <% Html.RenderPartial("LoginUserControl"); %>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        });
    </script>
    <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("pageinit", "#master-page", function () {
            $(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", "#master-page", function (e) {
                // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
                // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
                // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
                if ($.mobile.activePage.jqmData("panel") !== "open") {
                    if (e.type === "swipeleft") {
                        $("#right-panel").panel("open");
                    } else if (e.type === "swiperight") {
                        $("#leftpanel").panel("open");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptsSection" runat="server" />
</body>
```

I want to load and apply CSS/JQuery in the Android WebView. I want to keep the files in android mobile app and apply them as the page loads inside the webView.

If I don't load these files in specific order the design breaks. The reason I want to do this to make sure user don't feel its a web app. At present at each refresh/reload it takes about 1-2 seconds for jquery mobile and css to load.

Since MVC4 pages are compiled on remote server, Is it possible?

Comment: put those files in your assets folder and use them in your webpage...

Comment: @nj How? How can I refer them in the MVC4 pages on my server?? You mean I should just simply use the "file://asset" path in my asp.net master page?

Comment: yes , i think that will work and to enable javascript use object.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true) of your WebView;

Comment: I replaced one of the css file with this <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.min.css" /> and it broke the site design.

Comment: just use jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.min.css in href not the whole path :)

Comment: I tried <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.min.css" /> and <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.min.css" /> and installed a new app with "jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.min.css" file in assets folder. Result was same, no css design.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the comment on your question basically sums it up. You need to add the js/css code into your assets files.

If you want an example, you can take a look at this sample project (I only load js code, but it's the same principle for css)  [here](https://github.com/HarshEvilGeek/Android-JavaScript-Example)

To go over the general idea:

Make your webview use a custom WebViewClient (called MailWebViewClient in the example). You don't need a custom webview (as was done in the example) `wv.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);`

In your webview client, override the `onPageFinished()` method and load your javascript code in a string (src) `view.loadUrl("javascript: " + src);`

That's it. It should work fine

In the example, I'm loading a script that will resize all tables and images to fit inside the webview (a common requirement for android). There's also some haphazard linkify code (to identify and mark links). I wouldn't use the js code, since it's a little buggy, but it's a good example for the principle.

Comment: Akhil if i dont add the JS/CSS files (one linked in head section and body) in specific order, the page design breaks. As per your reply above if I use view.loadUrl("javascript: " + src); src contains rendered HTML output of aspx page, which contains link to JS/CSS files on my server. What does adding "javascript:" prefix to it does? Remember my MVC4 aspx pages are hosted on a live windows .net server. I am not following, kind of confused.

Comment: What I want to know is that, if I add files to asset folder. How do I add them to specific location inside the webpage that is loaded in webview. Since the file order matters.

Comment: I'm not sure why the order matters, and I'm fairly certain you can modify the code around that, but if that's what you want to do, you'll have to modify the html directly.

To do this, you could parse the response to your initial GET request for the webpage. You could then, insert your code in the appropriate places and pass the new output to be rendered in a webview. It'll be a little slower than a standard webview, but not by much

Comment: Order matters because file are dependent, like I can't load jquery mobile lib before loading jquery. The whole point of using local file is to improve the speed of design getting applied and page load. I could think of one solution which is caching static content. Its better compared to what I had already but still not fast enough. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

put All Css and JS in assets folder.

and try to load web view with :

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", <HTMLDATA> ,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: This looks like a option, but how can I specify the order in which files should be loaded and applied. The sequence is as follows 1) jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.min.css 2) jquery.mobile.icons.min.css 3) jquery-ui.datepicker.min.css 4) jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css 5) jquery-1.11.1.min.js 6) jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js is this possible?